# Сортировка json через js

Tags: javascript, json

Не получается отсортировать json -

```
[{"сумма": "100↵", "дата": "2021-05-25↵"}, 
{"сумма": "200↵", "дата": "2021-05-26↵"}}, 
{"сумма": "300↵", "дата": "2021-05-27↵"}]
```

Собственно делаю вот так вот

```
var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.дата.slice(0, -1) - b.дата.slice(0, -1);
});
```

И ничего, для суммы всё тоже самое работает

Может поможет:

```
var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)).sort(function(a, b) {
    console.log(a.дата.slice(0, -1))
    return a.дата.slice(0, -1) - b.дата.slice(0, -1);
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(js вообще не знаю)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может так вы хотите?

```js
let array = [{"сумма": "100↵", "дата": "2021-05-25↵"}, 
{"сумма": "200↵", "дата": "2021-05-26↵"}, 
{"сумма": "300↵", "дата": "2021-05-27↵"}];



array.sort((a, b) => (+(a["сумма"]).slice(0, -1)) - ((b["сумма"]).slice(0, -1)));
console.log("сортировка по возрастанию суммы");
console.log(array);
array.sort((a, b) => (+(b["сумма"]).slice(0, -1)) - ((a["сумма"]).slice(0, -1)));
console.log("сортировка по убыванию суммы");
console.log(array);


array.sort((a, b) => new Date(a["дата"].slice(0, -1)) - new Date(b["дата"].slice(0, -1)));
console.log("сортировка по возрастанию даты");
console.log(array);
array.sort((a, b) => new Date(b["дата"].slice(0, -1)) - new Date(a["дата"].slice(0, -1)));
console.log("сортировка по убыванию даты");
console.log(array);
```

К основному вопросу почему не работает

```js
let array = [{"сумма": "100↵", "дата": "2021-05-25↵"}, 
{"сумма": "200↵", "дата": "2021-05-26↵"}, 
{"сумма": "300↵", "дата": "2021-05-27↵"}];


array.forEach(a => console.log(a.сумма.slice(0, -1)));
array.forEach(a => console.log(a.дата.slice(0, -1)));
```

Как видно из примера вы изменяете исходную строку на `item.slice(0, -1)` но этого мало нужно преобразовать строки в сравниваемый тип иначе это будет всего лишь сравнение строк, который будет работать для суммы, поскольку операция "-" не определена для строк, автоматом переведет в "number",

```js
let array = [{"сумма": "1050↵", "дата": "2021-05-25↵"}, 
{"сумма": "1020↵", "дата": "2021-05-26↵"}, 
{"сумма": "103↵", "дата": "2021-05-27↵"}];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.сумма.slice(0, -1) - b.сумма.slice(0, -1);
});

console.log(array);
```

а дату он попытается перевести "2021-05-25" в number но не получится и сортировки не будет

```js
let array = [{"сумма": "1050↵", "дата": "2021-05-25↵"}, 
{"сумма": "1020↵", "дата": "2021-05-26↵"}, 
{"сумма": "103↵", "дата": "2021-05-27↵"}];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.дата.slice(0, -1) - b.дата.slice(0, -1);
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Ошибся сумма у меня то же вот так выглядит "сумма": "100↵"

Comment: @Leonid подправил ответ добавил недостающий элемент

Comment: работает, спасибо большое!)

Comment: Не за что пользуетесь на здоровье